# I want to run this code but I get error : syntax error near unexpected token done '<'

Tags: bash

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function check_dgmgrl {
  server_address="$1"
  dgmgrl_output=$(echo -e "connect /;\nshow configuration;\n" | dgmgrl / | grep "$server_address")
  echo "$dgmgrl_output" >> dgmgrl_output.txt
}

function check_srvctl {
  export ORACLE_SID="$1"
  echo "Service status for database $ORACLE_SID:"
  srvctl status service -db "$ORACLE_SID" >> service_status.txt
}

servers_file="Servers.txt"
while IFS= read -r server_address; do
  check_dgmgrl "$server_address"
done < "$servers_file"

while IFS=: read -r db_name db_home _; do

  if [[ "$db_name" =~ ^\#.*$|^$ ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  check_srvctl "$db_name"
done < <(grep -v '^#' /etc/oratab)
```

> line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

> ./check_health.sh: line 30: `done < <(grep -v '^#' /etc/oratab)'

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks

Comment: `<(...)` is a bash syntax called _Process Substitution_ Make sure you run your script with `bash` and not `sh`

Comment: @Matthew How do you expect that to work? That will require `grep` to return a filename.

Comment: It has to connect to each server and run dgmgrl and write them out put for each server but I wanted to read /etc/oratab because in this file we have a lot of db_name
@Matthew